# What's the best architecture for time series prediction with a long dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, prediction, time-series

I have to build a neural network without any architecture limitations which have to predict the next value of a time series.

The dataset is composed of 400.000 values, which are given in hex format. For example

```
0xbfb22b14
0xbfb22b10
0xbfb22b0c
0xbfb22b18
0xbfb22b14
```

I think LSTM is suitable for this problem, but I am worried about the length of the input. Would it be a good idea to use CNN?

```
def structure(step,n_features):
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(step, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    return model
```

What about this one ?

```
"model": {
        "loss": "mse",
        "optimizer": "adam",
    "save_dir": "saved_models",
        "layers": [
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 999,
                "input_timesteps": 998,
                "input_dim": 1,
                "return_seq": true
            },
            {
                "type": "dropout",
                "rate": 0.05
            },
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 100,
                "return_seq": false
            },
            {
                "type": "dropout",
                "rate": 0.05
            },
            {
                "type": "dense",
                "neurons": 1,
                "activation": "linear"
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LSTM are ideal for this. For even stronger representational capacity, make your LSTM's multi-layered.
Using 1-dimensional convolutions in a CNN is a common way to exctract information from time series too, so there's no harm in trying. Typically, you'll test many models out and take the one that has best validation performance.

Comment: We have tried this models but the loss is extremely big (quintillion scale). What do you suggest to do further ?

Comment: I added a new one , what do you think about it ? Whatever architecture I choose the training time is extremely big . Note that sequence length is 999 and I want to predict the 1000th .